# Is there an alternative "Date" data type that is more "ambiguous" than UTC?

Tags: date, datetime

The typical `Date` data type, in most programming languages, is a Unix timestamp that represents an "exact moment in time".

But I want to know if there's a more "ambiguous" `Date` structure, that more closely represents human perception of dates.

For example, say I want to represent a specific year (`2000`), or a specific month (`January 2000`), or a specific day (`January 1, 2000`)?
I could store it as a Unix timestamp, which would be `1/1/2000 12:00 AM GMT`.
But computers interpret timestamps according to its local timezone, so my computer would show `12/31/1999 5:00 PM PDT`, and each computer would interpret it differently.

Since Unix timestamps seems to be the standard for **exact** moments in time, I'm just wondering if there's any sort of standard for **ambiguous** moments in time.
If there's not a standard, I'd be happy to read about any specific implementations (**in any language**) that handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are many places you'll encounter this:

- In the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format.  For example `"2014-10-08"` is the 8th day of October, 2014.
- In .NET languages, such as C#, the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) type is a date and time, but it is not necessarily bound to a specific moment in time.  That depends on an internal property called `Kind`, which can be either `Utc`, `Local`, or `Unspecified`.  When it's unspecified, then it is just a date and time without reference to any time zone.  It still has a time component though.
- In the .NET library [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), the [`LocalDate`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_LocalDate.htm) type is a pure date without time or time zone.  Similarly, [`LocalDateTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_LocalDateTime.htm) is a date and time type without a time zone.
- In the Java library [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) type is a pure date without time or time zone.  Similarly, [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) is a date and time type without a time zone.  You'll also find these types in the new [`java.time` API in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).
- In C or C++, the [`tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) structure represents a calendar date and time, without regard to time zone.  It's in the standard library, along with the [`t_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) structure that has the behavior you described in your question.
- In Python, the [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object represents a date without a time or timezone.  The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object represents a date and time, with an *optional* time zone.  Python calls them *naive* when there is no time zone information present, and *aware* when a time zone is provided.
- In many databases, there are data types for date and time, or for date-only, without regard to time zone.  I won't list all databases, but consider Microsoft SQL Server which has separate [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) types.

I'm sure there are many others, however they don't necessarily exist for *all* languages.  For example, PHP has a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, but it's time zone aware, and I don't believe a class exists that isn't (or I couldn't find it anyway).   JavaScript is another example, as its [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object is really a date and time object that's bound to a UTC-based timestamp.

By the way, these types (and much more) are covered in the Pluralsight course, [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals), of which I am the author.  You may wish to check it out.

Comment: Amazing answer ... I actually feel bad for not realizing there were so many options.

Comment: I'm curious, how do these date types typically serialize their data? It seems like ISO string would be an easy choice, but I wonder if there's anything more elegant. (I'm brainstorming for a JavaScript solution)

Comment: ISO8601 is always the best bet for serialization.  What do you mean by more "elegant"?

Comment: I think an ISO8601 string would use like 10-20 bytes, whereas the Unix timestamp is 4 bytes.  But I guess it's just an implementation detail, and ISO has the big advantage of being human-readable.

Comment: Usually in JavaScript we're balancing human readability with compactness.  JSON is a great example.  There are always more compact formats.  You can get crazy with binary serialization protocols like Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), or the new [Spearal](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/beyond-json-introducing) format.  Personally, I prefer to stick to JSON because I like readability.

Comment: You could also do your own thing, such as send an integer of whole days since an epoch, but again that sacrifices readability.  That would be good as the internal representation of a date-only object, but not necessarily for serialization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62771/discussion-between-scott-rippey-and-matt-johnson).